# Get Default Gateway programmatically using getHostAddress() from InetAddress class

Tags: android, ip, tcp, gateway

I want to get Default gateway in Android programmatically. I found following solution first: [IP address of router in code answered by @Sandeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035784/how-to-know-ip-address-of-the-router-from-code-in-android)

Then I realised [formatIpAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatIpAddress%28int%29) is deprecated. As documentation described : We can `getHostAddress()`

I also thought, it is better since I may not need to add new permissions to my app as @Sandeep mentioned in his answer:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I used following solution to `get default gateway` as for instance mentioned in : [How to get default gateway using Ethernet, not wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942291/how-to-get-default-gateway-using-ethernet-not-wifi)

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This solution will not return Default Gateway as `dhcp.gateway` provided for me. But then how can I get default gateway as [documentation mentioned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatIpAddress%28int%29) by using `getHostAddress()` ?

**Addenda**:

As it is mentioned in the comment under [IP address of router in code answered by @Sandeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035784/how-to-know-ip-address-of-the-router-from-code-in-android), what if I disabled `DHCP`? then `DhcpInfo` will not work as I expected.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am struggling to find a way of determining the gateway without DHCP.

Comment: @EmilS. This is an old question but as far as I remember, there were no solution.